# Entity Framework ..Lambda Expression (Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object')

Tags: entity-framework

I want Entity Framework Lambda Expression Query for this particular SQL Query

```
     select Name from EmpMaster Where Code=163
```

I tried

```
string markedto= db.EmpMaster.Where(x => x.Code == 163).Select(x => x.Name).ToString();
```

But this is giving this error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.EmpMaster.Where(x => x.Code == 163).Select(x => x.Name)` is an `IQueryable<string>`. To get a single string value from it, use `Single()`...

```
string markedto = db.EmpMaster
                     .Where(x => x.Code == 163)
                     .Select(x => x.Name)
                     .Single();
```